# How to Eval Label in Repeater from cell of DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, repeater

My repeater has Item and AlternatingItem templates.
I've Label A In ItemTemplate and In Label B AlternatingItemTemplate .
Trying to bind data to Label A if ListItemTemlateType is Item and also  bind data to Label B if ListItemTemlateType is AlternatingItem from my DataTable

```
LabelColor.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["Data"].ToString();
```

With this pieces of code binding same value always.

How can i bind involved data properly?

Answer (score 0):

Tried that and helped..

```
            DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label LabelColor = e.Item.FindControl("LabelColor") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item && LabelColor != null)
            {
                LabelColor.Text = drv.Row["ColorLotName"].ToString(); 
            }
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label LabelColorAlternating = e.Item.FindControl("LabelColorAlternating") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem && LabelColorAlternating != null)
            {
                LabelColorAlternating.Text = drv.Row["ColorLotName"].ToString();            
            }
```